# Limiting database security

Tags: security, database

A number of texts signify that the most important aspects offered by a DBMS are availability, integrity and secrecy. As part of a homework assignment I have been tasked with mentioning attacks which would affect each aspect. This is what I have come up with - are they any good?

```
Availability - DDOS attack Integrity
Secrecy - SQL Injection attack
Integrity - Use of trojans to gain access to objects with higher security roles
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those examples are applicable to those metrics.

An unrestricted SQL injection attack will often compromise both the confidentiality of the system and the integrity of it, since data in the system can retrieved by the attacker (confidentiality) as well as modified (integrity).  However, a properly secured system will often use limited privileges for database users - for instance, if the application user only has `SELECT` rights, and not any of the modify operations, then the integrity of the system is not at risk.

The [CVSS scoring system](http://www.first.org/cvss/cvss-guide#i2.1.4) is a good reference point for the different impacts that a vulnerability can have on a system, and is the industry standard for rating vulnerabilities - it's a good thing to be familiar with!